# gunicorn_django error "cannot find myproject.settings in your PYTHONPATH"

Tags: python, gunicorn

I can run gunicorn_django on the root dir of my project, but when i set all thing in supervisor I got this error message "Error: Can't find 'myproject.settings' in your PYTHONPATH."

my supervisor setting:

```
command=/usr/local/django/myproject/gunicorn_django -c   /usr/local/django/myproject/gunicorn.conf.py 
directory=/usr/local/django/myproject 
user=www-data 
autostart=true
autorestart=true 
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log
redirect_stderr=true
```

gunicorn_django configure file gunicorn.conf.py

```
bind = "127.0.0.1:9004" 
logfile ="/var/www/vhosts/myproject.net/log/gunicorn.log" 
workers = 3
```

**UPDATE:** problem solved, it was because that www-data didn't have the read permission to settings.py and other files needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure `gunicorn` is in your `INSTALLED_APPS` and change `command` to this:

```
command=/path/to/python /path/to/manage.py run_gunicorn -c /path/to/gunicorn.conf.py
```

Comment: thanks, after I changed to this command I got more detailed error informaton,it is a file permission thing

Comment: what did you do to fix it exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Also, check for missing Python dependencies. I've had Django crash in a similar fashion when there were missing Python libs.